# Windows 2016 Borwnout on Azure Copy Task

Tags: azure, azure-devops

We have been using the Azure copy task in devops for the last year.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-file-copy?view=azure-devops

Until this week it was fine, but now on the execution of the task it is failing with:

This is a scheduled windows-2016 brownout. The windows-2016 environment is deprecated and will be removed on July 31, 2022. For more details, see https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/issues/5403

The problem I have is the step does not allow us to set the machine (that I can see) to target windows latest. In the documentation, it's just a powershell script.

Has anyone else fixed this issue or migrated to another step that resolves it?

Answer (score 0):

The message is referring to the agent that your pipeline is running on. You're correct: You don't choose the agent pool at the task level. You choose it at the job or stage level.